Randomness in substrate pallets
We are creating a price guessing game as a substrate pallet. We would like to fetch random objects from an API for the game. What options can we use to get randomness within our pallet?

https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7502/how-to-implement-a-production-randomness-pallet

https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/121/secure-random-number-generation
